# How to Handle Drawing a Rectangle if the Mouse Moves Outside of the Canvas Bounds

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have some code that draws rectangles on a `Canvas`. This all works great, however, when the mouse leaves the bounds of the `Canvas`, the drawing of the rectangle freezes and nothing happens. Some code

```xml
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown" MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove" MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp" Background="Transparent" />
```

```
private Point startPoint;
private Rectangle rect;

private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    startPoint = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    rect = new Rectangle
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.LightBlue,
        StrokeThickness = 2
    };
    Canvas.SetLeft(rect,startPoint.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect,startPoint.X);
    canvas.Children.Add(rect);
}

private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released || rect == null)
        return;

    var pos = e.GetPosition(canvas);

    var x = Math.Min(pos.X, startPoint.X);
    var y = Math.Min(pos.Y, startPoint.Y);

    var w = Math.Max(pos.X, startPoint.X) - x;
    var h = Math.Max(pos.Y, startPoint.Y) - y;

    rect.Width = w;
    rect.Height = h;

    Canvas.SetLeft(rect, x);
    Canvas.SetTop(rect, y);
}

private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    rect = null;
}
```

What I want is for the drawing to the rectangle to continue, even when I go out-side the bounds of the `Canvas`, but obviously the dimension of the rectangle clipped to the boundary of the `Canvas`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture the mouse in the MouseDown handler

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    canvas.CaptureMouse();
    ...
}
```

and release the capture in the MouseUp handler

```
private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}
```